# MySQL analog of PostgreSQL VALUES statement?

Tags: mysql

In PostgreSQL we have [VALUES statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-values.html).

For example,

```
VALUES (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three');
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT 1 AS column1, 'one' AS column2
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'two'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'three';
```

What is analog in MySQL?

Comment: The select statement in the second block.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support the (standard) row constructor using VALUES. It is supported for an INSERT statement, but never as a "standalone" statement.